# Are there array creation expressions in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

In C#, I can use an expression like this:

```
void doStuffOnArray(int[] array) {...}
doStuffOnArray(new int[] {0, 2, 4, 6, 8});
```

is there an equivalent one-liner in Java? Or do I have to stick with

```
int[] temp = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8};
doStuffOnArray(temp);
```

?

Comment: c# uses the same syntax as java.

Comment: 1. what does the compiler say? 2. What does the tutorial say?

Comment: @Bozho - it works out of the box, I must have left my brain somewhere when I asked this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly the same syntax works:

```
doStuffOnArray(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the syntax is exactly the same in java! :)